# Database Sync - Local and Online without Replication

Tags: c#, php, database, mysql-8.0

So I have this `code` that checks if new data is added to `online database` by comparing the `rows` of `online and local database`. If new data is found it inserts the new data to `local database`.

```
public class Reservation
{
    public string res_no { get; set; }
    public string mem_fname { get; set; }
}
```

**My Code :**

```
private async void updateDineList()
    {
            DBconnector.OpenConnection();

            //Gets data from online database
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync("http://example.com/Reservation/view_pending_reservation");
            var persons = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Reservation>>(response);

            //Gets data from Local database
            string string_reservation = "SELECT res_no,mem_fname  FROM res_no WHERE res_status='pending';";
            DataTable reservation_table = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter_reservartion = new MySqlDataAdapter(string_reservation, DBconnector.Connection);
            adapter_reservartion.Fill(reservation_table);

            //Gets the row of each table
            int local = reservation_table.Rows.Count;
            int online = persons.Count;

            //Compares rows of online and local database
            if (local < online)
            {   
            //if the rows of online database is greater than local database
            //inserts the new data from local database
                string Command_membership = "INSERT INTO reservation_details (res_no,mem_fname) VALUES (@res_no, @mem_fname);";                    
                for (int i = local; i < online; i++)
                {
                    //inserts new data from online to local database
                    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(Command_membership, DBconnector.Connection))
                    {
                        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@res_no", persons[i].res_no);
                        myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mem_fname", persons[i].mem_fname);
                        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                }
                MessageBox.Show("New Records Found");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No new Records");
            }

            DBconnector.Connection.Close();
    }
```

So my question is there any problem could occur with this code, it works fine but is there any way to improve this. I know MySQL replication is better but I am only using free `Web Hosting` with few MySQL privileges.

Comment: It depends how you are using both databases, what is adding to them both, and why. Replication and sync functionality is there for a reason, its built to be reliable and has known quantities. The problem with cheap solutions is you get cheap and sometimes unexpected results. Your code does what it does, and there its not obvious that there are any oversights because we don't know the system usages and domains and i doubt we ever will in this question and answer format.  I suggest (if you don't want to do this replication and the utilities designed to do this) is trial it and see

Comment: Anyway i am voting to close this question, as its more of a code review, more than a little too broad, and is low quality for the spirit of this site

Comment: Thanks Sir I appreciate your answer. Maybe ill try buying vps to perform replication.

Answer (score 1):

The clear improvement is not to create a new command for every row. You should either create the command and parameters once and then set the parameters and call for each row, or better still package the set of updates into a single structure, like and xml string, and then pass the whole lot to the database via a stored procedure call.

Other probably problematic issue is that you are checking purely based on row counts. Don't know if that is valid in your scenario but it sounds dangerous. What if rows are deleted? or is that not possible in your scenario. Some other way of checking last updates would probably be preferable.

Without more context that's about all I can see.